# How to execute minishift to CentOS7 on EC2

Tags: openshift, minishift

I'm trying create a OpenShift cluster with minishift, on AWS EC2.

When following command executes, an error occurs and stop building.

```
$ ./minishift start --vm-driver generic --remote-ipaddress <remote_IP_address> --remote-ssh-user <username> --remote-ssh-key <private_ssh_key>
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'generic' hypervisor ...
-- Preparing Remote Machine ......................................... OK
-- Starting to provision the remote machine ........... FAIL E1110 12:30:16.999357    2234 start.go:491] Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: generic driver does not support start. Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: generic driver does not support start
```

version:

```
$ ./minishift version
minishift v1.26.1+1e20f27
```

refs:
https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/using/run-against-an-existing-machine.html

---

On minishift `v1.27.0+707887e`, another error occurs.

(Before executing following `minishift start` command, `remote user` is required [belonging to `docker` group](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user).)

```
$ minishift start --vm-driver generic --remote-ipaddress 18.233.158.63 --remote-ssh-user centos --remote-ssh-key /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'generic' hypervisor ...
-- Preparing Remote Machine ...... OK
-- Starting to provision the remote machine .................... OK
-- OpenShift cluster will be configured with ...
Version: v3.11.0
-- Pulling the OpenShift Container Image ......... OK
-- Copying oc binary from the OpenShift container image to VM ... OK
-- Starting OpenShift cluster ......................................................................Error during 'cluster up' execution: Error starting the cluster. ssh command error:
command : /var/lib/minishift/bin/oc cluster up --base-dir /var/lib/minishift/base --image 'openshift/origin-${component}:v3.11.0' --public-hostname 18.233.158.63 --routing-suffix 18.233.158.63.nip.io
err     : exit status 1
output  : Getting a Docker client ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 is available ...
Pulling image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11.0
E1115 03:45:41.309220   11696 helper.go:173] Reading docker config from /home/centos/.docker/config.json failed: open /home/centos/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory, will attempt to pull image docker.io/openshift/origin-cli:v3.11.0 anonymously
Image pull complete
Pulling image openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0
E1115 03:45:41.480331   11696 helper.go:173] Reading docker config from /home/centos/.docker/config.json failed: open /home/centos/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory, will attempt to pull image docker.io/openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0 anonymously
Pulled 6/6 layers, 100% complete
Extracting
Image pull complete
Checking type of volume mount ...
Determining server IP ...
Using public hostname IP 18.233.158.63 as the host IP
Checking if OpenShift is already running ...
Checking for supported Docker version (=>1.22) ...
Checking if insecured registry is configured properly in Docker ...
Checking if required ports are available ...
Checking if OpenShift client is configured properly ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 is available ...
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 ...
I1115 03:45:47.686207   11696 config.go:40] Running "create-master-config"
I1115 03:45:50.350386   11696 config.go:46] Running "create-node-config"
I1115 03:45:51.702066   11696 flags.go:30] Running "create-kubelet-flags"
I1115 03:45:52.085289   11696 run_kubelet.go:49] Running "start-kubelet"
I1115 03:45:52.249024   11696 run_self_hosted.go:181] Waiting for the kube-apiserver to be ready ...
I1115 03:46:20.265246   11696 interface.go:26] Installing "kube-proxy" ...
I1115 03:46:20.265835   11696 interface.go:26] Installing "kube-dns" ...
I1115 03:46:20.265843   11696 interface.go:26] Installing "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator" ...
I1115 03:46:20.265849   11696 interface.go:26] Installing "openshift-apiserver" ...
I1115 03:46:20.265897   11696 apply_template.go:81] Installing "openshift-apiserver"
I1115 03:46:20.266386   11696 apply_template.go:81] Installing "kube-proxy"
I1115 03:46:20.268284   11696 apply_template.go:81] Installing "kube-dns"
I1115 03:46:20.268428   11696 apply_template.go:81] Installing "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator"
I1115 03:46:23.999620   11696 interface.go:41] Finished installing "kube-proxy" "kube-dns" "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator" "openshift-apiserver"
Error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Comment: Have you configured the remote machine properly? (https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/using/run-against-an-existing-machine.html#configuring-existing-remote-machine) 
And is the remote machine reachable from your host via ssh?

Comment: Yes, I can login using `ssh <user>@<remote_IP_address>` without password input.